# error in symfony for manyToOne and form imbricated

Tags: symfony

I encountered a problem under symfony3 which has blocked me for a while ... I do not understand this error:

```
Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\Project#$participants", got "string" instead.
```

Here is my entity Project:

```
class Project
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="projects")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Participant", mappedBy="project", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $participants;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="place", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $place;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateEvent", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateEvent;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean")
 */
private $status;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="in_progress", type="boolean")
 */
private $inProgress;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="accept_list", type="boolean")
 */
private $acceptList;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="visible_list", type="boolean")
 */
private $visibleList;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="many_loop", type="boolean")
 */
private $manyLoop;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="text_email", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $textEmail;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
 */
private $created;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->run          = false;
    $this->status       = false;
    $this->acceptList   = true;
    $this->visibleList  = true;
    $this->inProgress   = false;
    $this->manyLoop     = true;
    $this->created      = new \Datetime('now');
    $this->participants = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set place
 *
 * @param string $place
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setPlace($place)
{
    $this->place = $place;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get place
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPlace()
{
    return $this->place;
}

/**
 * Set dateEvent
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateEvent
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setDateEvent($dateEvent)
{
    $this->dateEvent = $dateEvent;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateEvent
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateEvent()
{
    return $this->dateEvent;
}

/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param boolean $status
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get status
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * Set inProgress
 *
 * @param boolean $inProgress
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setInProgress($inProgress)
{
    $this->inProgress = $inProgress;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get inProgress
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getInProgress()
{
    return $this->inProgress;
}

/**
 * Set acceptList
 *
 * @param boolean $acceptList
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setAcceptList($acceptList)
{
    $this->acceptList = $acceptList;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get acceptList
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getAcceptList()
{
    return $this->acceptList;
}

/**
 * Set visibleList
 *
 * @param boolean $visibleList
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setVisibleList($visibleList)
{
    $this->visibleList = $visibleList;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get visibleList
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getVisibleList()
{
    return $this->visibleList;
}

/**
 * Set manyLoop
 *
 * @param boolean $manyLoop
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setManyLoop($manyLoop)
{
    $this->manyLoop = $manyLoop;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get manyLoop
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getManyLoop()
{
    return $this->manyLoop;
}

/**
 * Set textEmail
 *
 * @param string $textEmail
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setTextEmail($textEmail)
{
    $this->textEmail = $textEmail;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get textEmail
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTextEmail()
{
    return $this->textEmail;
}

/**
 * Set created
 *
 * @param \DateTime $created
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setCreated($created)
{
    $this->created = $created;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get created
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreated()
{
    return $this->created;
}

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * Add participant
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Participant $participant
 *
 * @return Project
 */
public function addParticipant(\AppBundle\Entity\Participant $participant)
{
    $this->participants[] = $participant;

    // On lie l'annonce à la candidature
    $participant->setProject($this);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove participant
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Participant $participant
 */
public function removeParticipant(\AppBundle\Entity\Participant $participant)
{
    $this->participants->removeElement($participant);
}

/**
 * Get participants
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getParticipants()
{
    return $this->participants;
}}
```

My Form:

```
$builder ->add('participants', ParticipantType::class);

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function configureOptions (OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Project',
        'step' => 1,
    ));
}
```

Form imbricated :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('lastName', TextType::class, array(
            'required'  => true,
            'label'     => 'Nom'
        ))
        ->add('firstName', TextType::class, array(
            'required'  => true,
            'label'     => 'Prénom'
        ))
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
            'required'  => true,
            'label'     => 'Adresse mail'
        ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => array('registration')
    ));
}
```

So here is to summarize my problem, I do not understand the error that Symfony returns, yet from the examples on the internet I do not see why there is a problem here ...

If someone to a solution would be top, because I blocked on this problem for a long time ...

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't forget to add : `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` or use `$this->participants = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();`

Comment: Yes I have the arrayColletion in my entity

Answer (score 0):

In your `FormType` you should configure the `participants` field as a collection of `Participant`. It should be done using `CollectionType` like this:

```
$builder->add('participants', CollectionType::class, array(
  'entry_type' => ParticipantType::class,
  'allow_add' => true,
  ...
));
```

**EDIT**
According to your data model, the `participants` Field is a collection of `Participant` object. As you can see in the error message you presented, an array is expected.  The `CollectionType` will always return an array of the target type.
That is why I suggest you to consider using a `CollectionType` in your form type. You can learn more about CollectionType [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) and about Symfony forms in general [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html)

Comment: Change line `'entry_type' => ParticipantType::class` to  `'class' => ParticipantType::class`

Comment: No @adashbob the `class` option does not exist for the `CollectionType`  in symfony 3.  Have a look at this link to learn more http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html